# Python parse empty string

Tags: python

I'm using the [`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) library and ran into surprising (to me) functionality: it does not match empty strings:

```
>>> from parse import parse
>>> parse('hi "{}"', 'hi "everybody"')
<Result ('everybody',) {}>
>>> parse('hi "{}"', 'hi ""')
>>>
```

Is there a way, using `parse`, to get it to match any string between `""` in the same way that `re` does:

```
>>> from re import match
>>> match('hi "(.*)"', 'hi "everybody"').groups()
('everybody',)
>>> match('hi "(.*)"', 'hi ""').groups()
('',)
```

Comment: The `""` inside of `'hi ""'` isn't an empty string.

Comment: @mattm The point is that the string between the `"`s is empty.

Comment: No. That's what I'm trying to say. There is no string between the `"`'s, just as there is no string between the `h` and the `i` in `'hi'`.

Comment: @mattm I haven't the slightest idea what it is you're trying to say. I **know** there's no string between the `"`s. I want `parse` to give me back an empty string in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom type conversion:

```
from parse import parse
def zero_or_more_string(text):
    return text

zero_or_more_string.pattern = r".*"
parse('hi "{:z}"', 'hi ""', { "z": zero_or_more_string })
```

and you'll get this:

```
<Result ('',) {}>
```